# SQL change word command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcommand

How to change the location of the letters 5 and 6 in sql. For example:

```
word:weather  new word:weatehr
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Sql server 2014 use and replicate command but dont change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `SUBSTRING` with `LEN` function to make it.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col varchar(40)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('weather')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
 col 'word' ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING(col,1,4),SUBSTRING(col,6,1),SUBSTRING(col,5,1),SUBSTRING(col,7,LEN(col) - 5)) 'new word'
    FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94183/3)**:

```
|    word | new word |
|---------|----------|
| weather |  weatehr |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(32) = 'weather';
set @s = stuff(@s, 5, 2, reverse(substring(@s, 5, 2)));
```

Since you're just reversing adjacent characters it's a little easier than swapping arbitrary characters.